# How to get values inside the entities in tweepy api.get_user method(python)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

This is my code

```
consumerKey=" "
consumerSecret=" "
accessToken=" "
accessSecret=" "

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken,accessSecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

customerinfo = api.get_user('@ABC')
print "entities :",customerinfo.entities
```

output :

```
entities : {u'description': {u'urls': [{u'url': u'https:/t.co/fdsfdsdsff',
u'indices': [56, 79], u'expanded_url': u'http:/www.facebook.com/fsdfds',
u'display_url': u'facebook.com/dfsfds'}, {u'url': u'https:/t.co/dfdsfdsfds',
u'indices': [82, 105], u'expanded_url': u'http:/www.instagram.com/fsdfsdfds',
u'display_url': u'instagram.com/dfdsfdsfds'}]}}
```

How can I get urls values to a variables???

I tried customerinfo.entities.description and customerinfo.entities.urls
but it does not work.

Comment: Entities appears to be a *dictionary*; have you tried accessing its contents by keys? What precisely is the error message you're getting (*"does not work"* being very little to go on)? Have you read the library docs?

Comment: I am new to tweepy and python can u send me the link to library doc.

Comment: ...are you new to googling things? http://www.tweepy.org/

Comment: got the doc  Thnks

Answer (score 2):

`customerinfo entities` are of `dict` type.There are two ways to access values in a *dictionary* using *key* name:

```
a). customerinfo.entities['description']['urls']
b). customerinfo.entities.get('description').get('urls')
```

Method a). will return `KeyError` if no such key exists. 
Method b). will return `None` if no such key exists. 
hence, method b). is more preferable when you don't have confirmation of existence of key in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because variable "entities" is a "dictionary" type. Please have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html section: **5.8. Mapping Types — dict**. You need to get an access through the "key" value, as follow:

```
customerinfo.entities['description']
customerinfo.entities['description']['urls']
```

and so on. It's usually a good practise to check documentation before you ask the question.

Comment: Tnku @Karol Thnku for the advices. :)